# Camel FTP - FTP consumer for known filenames

Tags: ftp, apache-camel, polling

Is there a way to request files from an FTP endpoint if the name is known? In our case we want to retrieve files depending on date and time from a folder structure that is huge - listing recursively through the folder takes too long. I know the names of the files and locations to call for in advance (they are calculable from date and time), so scanning is just waste of time. I'd rather poll for the exact file I want until I successfully received it.

What is the best approach for this?

Cheers,
Kai

Answer (score 1):

By definition camel file and ftp components only poll directories.

You can use a combination of maxMessagesPerPoll and fileName to achieve your purpose, like

```
from("ftp://.../xyz?maxMessagesPerPoll=x&fileName=y");
```

fileName can be an expression. Take a look at camel file2 and ftp2 site.

Answer (score 0):

I know that to get specific files whose file names are known beforehand, you can use filtering approach.

This is given with an example in the official documentation but I'm not sure of it saving the time you'd spend in scanning the working directory.

Search for filter in the '[ftp page](http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html)'

Comment: this is just what I want to avoid, to filter the list of files that I have to retrieve first. the folder contains more than 6000 entries, the time alone to retrieve that goes into seconds. Not to mention polling that quite often. I need to retrieve certain files known by name and path and I have to retry when they aren't there yet.

Comment: Yeah. I understand your concern and am sorry that I can't provide a working solution here. Even I will keep a lookout for an effective solution to this.