# download specific file with camel and shutdown

Tags: apache-camel, ftp-client

Can i download with camel a specific file list from a sftp server and then shutdown the service?
I know this should be a common question but i can't figure out how to do it without waiting the context stopping.

In some way, camel can ensure data integrity?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do something like this using a direct route, [pollEnrich](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html#ContentEnricher-Contentenrichmentusing%7B%7BpollEnrich%7D%7D) and a template

```
from("direct:grabOneFile")
   .pollEnrich("sftp://somewhere/blah/blah?fileName=foobar");
```

then from some java code somewhere, just grab a [camel template](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) and invoke the "direct:grabOneFile route.

```
String ret = template.requestBody("direct:grabOneFile","",String.class);
```

In this case, you don't have to worry about when to shut down the camel context with the chance of having multiple files etc.

Comment: If you want to use the xml way, below is the sample: <pollEnrich>
            <constant>sftp://test@localhost:22/test?privateKeyFile=/keyFile&amp;disconnect=true</constant>
        </pollEnrich>

Answer (score 0):

Camel ftp component can only poll directories.
You can use a combination of maxMessagesPerPoll and fileName, like

```
from("ftp://.../xyz?maxMessagesPerPoll=x&fileName=y");
```

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489288/camel-ftp-ftp-consumer-for-known-filenames/15491502#15491502).

[This](http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html) link has examples regarding shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this out at the bottom of the [Camel FTP](http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html) page.